# Import same css file twice inside React component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, import

I know its bad practice to import the same file twice, but I have a situation where I need to import css based on user color selection.

[image]

Based on user selection I am importing css file in my header component so that it update css for all component.

```
componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.props.setting && this.props.setting.result) {
        // document.head.lastChild.remove();
        if (this.props.setting.result.brandColor === "Green") {
            require("../../scss/AppGreen.scss");
        } else if (this.props.setting.result.brandColor === "Red") {
            require("../../scss/AppRed.scss");
        } else if (this.props.setting.result.brandColor === "Yellow") {
            require("../../scss/AppYellow.scss");
        } else if (this.props.setting.result.brandColor === "LightBlue") {
            require("../../scss/AppLightBlue.scss");
        } else {
            require("../../scss/App.scss");
        }
    }
}
```

It's working fine when I first click on any color box but if I click on same color box again, css file don't get imported because it's already imported. Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Rather than managing styling by importing a specific CSS file, I'd recommend doing something like applying a class to your container based on the brand color selected, and then writing a single CSS file that applies specific styles based on the class

Comment: Agree with previous answer. CSS stand for cascading. So it's easy to implement logic to change color palette.

Comment: Amm, yes but my designer gave me CSS as separate files.

Comment: Your designer shouldn't organize CSS like that.
He should merge all css files in one (specially for this purpose), and using CSS selectors.

You can get different approaches with React and CSS.
https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html, 
styled-components library is intuitive (updating css style following component's state and props).
https://styled-components.com/